# UINavigation Controller and UIWeb View Navigation

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am writing an Xcode Application that has the following structure:

UINavigationController
   UITableView
      Option 1 Something else 
      Option 2 Something else
      Option 3 UIWebView

Within my web view I have an internal web page with a drill down structure:

UIWebView
      Option 1
             Option a 
                Detail from a
             Option b
                Detail from b
             Option c
             Option d
      Option 2
      Option 3

etc.

The navigation up to the UIWeb view is handled by iOS; the navigation once I get the UIWeb view is handled by the web page.

The problem is that I am showing the navigation bar from iOS in the first UIWebView Web page, which  want to do, but not in subsequent pages.

How can I handle the handoff of navigation?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured this out.

It really isn't anything to do with Xpages, but with using UIWebViews within iOS.

The problem was that on the first webView, I wanted to show the iOS Navigation, but in any subsequent ones I didn't want to - would just prefer to use the web navigation.

There is a delegation method in iOS Web views that allows you to show or hide the navigation bar. I added this delegate and just check to see which page I am on. If on the first one, I show the iOS Navigation, else I suppress.

This works great!